# Spresense SDKのWorker側の処理のパフォーマンス測定する良い方法はあるでしょうか。

Tags: spresense

現在、Spresense SDKを使ってWorkerに処理をオフロードする実装をしています。

Worker側に移した処理がどの程度時間がかかっているのか、を測りたいのですが、
何か良い方法はあるでしょうか。

Coretex-M4のCPUカウンタとか、使えるのでしょうか。
Workerでの使い方など、よくわからないので、知っている方がいたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

やりたいこと：
Worker側で、

```
   while(1){
      処理１();
      処理２();
   }
```

というようなコードがあった場合に、
メインコアだと、gettimeofday()などを使って、
時刻差からかかった時間を取ったりできるのですが、
Workerだと、このようなAPIが使えない、ということのようですが、
何か良い方法があれば。。と思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMSISにあるSYSTICKを使ってみるのはいかがでしょうか。

SYSTICKタイマーが24bitの減算カウンタなので、CPUクロック@156MHzの場合、最大107msec程度の時間であれば測定できると思います。

WorkerのMakefileにCMSISのインクルードパスを追加します。

```
CFLAGS += ${shell $(INCDIR) $(INCDIROPT) "$(CC)" "$(SDKDIR)/../externals/cmsis/CMSIS_5/CMSIS/Core/Include"}
CFLAGS += ${shell $(INCDIR) $(INCDIROPT) "$(CC)" "$(SDKDIR)/../externals/cmsis/CMSIS_5/Device/ARM/ARMCM4/Include"}
```

たとえば、以下のようなコードで処理１のCPUクロック数を測定することができます。

```c
#include "ARMCM4_FP.h"

  SysTick->LOAD = 0xffffff;
  SysTick->VAL = 0UL;
  SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;

  uint32_t start = SysTick->VAL;
  処理１();
  uint32_t elapsed = start - SysTick->VAL;
```

ご参考まで～。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
試してみます